# Generate all subsets of size k for specific item from a map std::map<std::pair< int, int>, int>

Tags: c++, dictionary, combinations

I failed to write a functions that generate all possible combinations (n chose k)  of map std::map, int>

for example: I create this map, Mymap

```
(( 1, 2 ), 1)
(( 1, 3 ), 1)
(( 1, 4 ), 1)
(( 2, 3 ), 2)
(( 2, 4 ), 3)
(( 2, 5 ), 1)
(( 3, 4 ), 2)
(( 5, 4 ), 1)
```

based on `Mymap`, I want to generate all possible combinations (n chose k), where n (1,2,3,4,5), and k is the size of the subset.

in more, details, based on `Mymap`, we can find that:

1: exists in the pair ( 1, 2 ), ( 1, 3 ), and ( 1, 4 )

this gives me the first set {2,3, 4} that I want to generate all its possible combinations only for '1'

if k =2 then, the combinations of '1' is:

```
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,3,4
```

in specific, i want to save the results in new map '**Mymap2**' like:

```
((1,2) (1,3), 2) // number 2 because I add the values for these two pairs (( 1, 2 ), 1) + (( 1, 3 ), 1)

((1,2) (1,4), 2)
((1,3) (1,4), 2)
```

then, I Do the same for '2'

2: exists in the pair ( 1, 2 ), ( 2, 3 ), ( 2, 4 ), and (2,5)

this gives me the set {1,3,4,5} that I want to generate all its possible combinations only for '2'

if k =2 then, the combinations of '2' is:

```
2,1,3
2,1,4
2,1,5
2,3,4
2,3,5
2,4,5
```

this results, will be store in Mymap2

```
 ((2,1) (2,3), 2)
 ((2,1) (2,4), 5)
 ((2,1) (2,5), 2)
 ((2,3) (2,4), 5)
 ((2,3) (2,5), 2)
 ((2,4) (2,5), 4)
```

and repeat the same steps, for 3 ,4,5

in order to do that, I create new map (std::map  > Item), where the k-value is (1,2,3,4,5), and the value is the set of associated items.

for example, map **Item** like :

```
(1, {2,3,4})
(2, {1,3,4,5})
(3, {1,2,4})
(4, {1,2,3,5})
(5, {2,4})
```

and this is the code for creating 'Item'

```
for (const auto& p1 : Mymap)
    {
        Item[p1.first.first].push_back(p1.first.second);
        Item[p1.first.second].push_back(p1.first.first);

    }
```

it also, gives me the size of each set, so, if the user set k=4, and we know that(for example) 1 is associated with 3 items,  we set k=3,

this is my code, which works only when k >= the number of associated items

for example: if we set k =3 or higher, and we want to test =(1, {2,3,4}), which means: 1  is associated with 3 items, then this code output correctly, but if k=2, then i will got error.

which works only when:

```
    int k = 0;
   std::map <int, vector <int> > Kcom;

    int i = 1;

    for (const auto& p1 : Item)
    {
        k=2;
        if (k > Item[p1.first].size())
            k = Item[p1.first].size();

        int count = 1;
        int c = 0;
        int j = Item[p1.first].size();



        while  (c != j)
        {
            cout << Item[p1.first].size();
            cout << "\n";


        while (count <= k)
            {

                 Kcom[i].push_back(p1.second[c]);
                ++c;
                ++count; 
            }
            ++i;
            // if j > k then
            //-----

            count = 1;

        }


    }
```

please help.

Comment: I edit the code, but still doesn't cover all cases.

Comment: this is another try, it gives me "error C2100: illegal indirection"   http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65837d6f42a10483